# Codeigniter : Adding array indexes in loop

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I am fetching news items from posts table in foreach loop  and attachments related to any this item are being fetched from attachments table .

i want to structure array like this

```
Array
(
    [news] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 95
            [date] => 2016-07-29
            [title] => This is first news
            [content] => This is first news details
            [type] => news
            ['attachment'] =>  stdClass Object
             (
              [id] => 25
              [attachment_id] => 95
              [type] => news
              [path] => Jellyfish23.jpg
           )

        )
```

this is how i am doing my loop

```
$posts=$this->db->get_where('posts',array('type'=>$type));
        if($posts->num_rows()>0){
            foreach ($posts->result() as $key=> $value) { 
                echo $value->id; 
                $res['news']=$posts->row();
                $result = $this->db->get_where('attachments', array('attachment_id'=>$value->id));
                $res['attachment']= $result->row();

            }

        }
```

this is what i get

```
Array
(
    [news] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 95
            [date] => 2016-07-29
            [title] => This is first news
            [content] => This is first news details
            [type] => news
        )

    [attachment] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 25
            [attachment_id] => 97
            [type] => news
            [path] => Jellyfish23.jpg
        )

)
```

Now how do i modify my code in a way that each news item and attachment related to that news are formatted properly as i mentioned above

Comment: This looks like you can just optimize your query by using a left join

Answer (score 2):

Use `$data = array();` to store your data after process

Just modify the line

`$res['attachment']= $result->row();`

to

`$res['news']['attachment']= $result->row();`

And use Array push $res to $total;

Because after each loop your $res has been overided but you don't store it

Full of code

```
$posts=$this->db->get_where('posts',array('type'=>$type));
$data = array();

if($posts->num_rows()>0){
    foreach ($posts->result() as $key=> $value) { 
        echo $value->id; 
        $res['news']=$posts->row();
        $result = $this->db->get_where('attachments', array('attachment_id'=>$value->id));
        $res['news']['attachment']= $result->row();
        array_push($data, $res);
    }
}

echo "<pre>";
var_dump($data);
echo "</pre>";
```